# What provides autocompletion? Shell or emulator?

Tags: linux, shell

I have been using Linux for some time now. Now, I have question about auto-completion of commands and directories in a terminal window.

When I press a `tab` key the terminal auto-completes or gives choice. Is this auto-completion provided by the shell or is it a feature of the emulator.

Also, if its provided by the terminal, how does a terminal provide it so transparently.

Comment: See the docs on the [GNU Readline library](http://www.gnu.org/s/readline/). (The FSF websites are down in protest of SOPA, so you might have to see [Google's cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:EQM8_BuQi8YJ:www.gnu.org/s/readline/+gnu+readline) of that page instead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell provides the auto-completion. It's not a separate script but built into the shell itself -- for standard file completion.

Auto-completion on arguments is built on the programmable completion facility built into `bash`. See the "[Programmable Completion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Programmable-Completion)" section of the bash man page.

Some Linux distributions provide the [bash_completion](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) package. This is a collection of configuration options which utilize the programmable completion commands in bash.

Answer (score 1):

the shell provides this. the terminal emulator draws what the shell produces and hands over user input to the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Auto completion is provided by the shell.
When Tab is pressed, the shell runs a script that decides, based on what you've typed already, what, exactly, needs to be completed. The script then generates a list of possible completions, which may or may not be the list of files in the current directory, or the list of executable files in your $PATH.

Comment: do you know the script that does it. Can a normal user use it?

Comment: The package which enable you to use "arguments completion" (as 'purge' after 'aptitude') is generally named 'bash-completion', see their homepage: http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/ and the ML Archive http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/bash-completion-devel/